# Dynamically creating button row column wise

Tags: android

I am pretty new to Android. I am trying to create buttons dynamically in android.

But all the buttons are coming vertically listed column wise.I would want 25 buttons to be distributed in 5 rows and 5 columns.

```
package com.sudarshan.tictactoenew;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.DynamicLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NumericalNextLevel extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numerical_next_level);
        createLayoutDynamically(5);
    }

    private void createLayoutDynamically(int n) {

        int count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                Button myButton = new Button(this);
                myButton.setText("");
                myButton.setId(count);

                final int id_ = myButton.getId();

                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myDynamicLayout);
                layout.addView(myButton);

                myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                count++;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: use a gridview instead of a linear layout

Comment: Hi Sudarshan , I have added one answer , you can try and if it is something you were looking for then mark it as right answer , it will help others also ! If it doesn't t work you can comment below the answer , Thanks !

Comment: Thanks it works.Most simple solution

Comment: actually , instead using linear layout such purpose you can go with grid layout in android , it is very useful for such purpose ,anyways I am glad it worked for you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this , as so far you are new but you have some Idea how Linea Layout works , so I am posting here code with Linear Layout !

Before going to Code let's undertand how it works , If you make layout using only linearlayout , it might be a trouble , becase Linear Layout set components in single direction like vertical or horizontal. but we can add multiple horiznotal Linearlayout in one Verttical Linear Layout then it will work like charm !

Here is rought drawaing what I am trying to say !

[image]

I have modified your function as below !

```html
 private void createLayoutDynamically(int n) {

        int count=0;
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myDynamicLayout); //Main Vertical Linear Layout
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); //Setting that LinearLayout as Vertical

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            LinearLayout row=new LinearLayout(this); //new Horizontal LinearLayout
            row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); //keeping this layout's orientation horizontal
            row.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); //setting it's width and Height

            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                Button myButton = new Button(this);
                myButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                myButton.setText("");
                myButton.setId(count);
                final int id_ = myButton.getId();
                row.addView(myButton);
                count++;
            }
            
            //Once Button Added to Horizontal Row add it back to Vertical Linearlayout
            layout.addView(row);

        }
    }
```

I have commented the lines so you can understand !

Answer (score 0):

You can use FlowLayout to do what you want with your buttons. Just replace your LinearLayout with FlowLayout.

[FlowLayout Library link](https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout)